# Create textfield and check box in adobe acrobat using itextsharp and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, acrobat

i want to create pdf in vb.net using itextsharp.dll. I have read articles about fillable pdf form , which can be created using  adobe acrobat .This is most suitable,if all the fields are static.My pdf has some dynamic parts also , the no:of textfields and check boxes are not fixed. Is there any way to create textfields and check box in adobe acrobat dynamicaly from vb.net

Answer (score 0):

If you have a predeterminated maximumm number of rows (assuming that you are talking of some kind of tabular form), you can create all of them, but make the "extra" ones hidden, and add some active element (for example a button) which the user can use to create (show) an extra line.

You may have to embed a bit more JavaScript code, and therefore, it might be a good idea to first create the form with all its logic in Acrobat, and then implement it using iText.